Can sequence 1, 1, 1, 1,.. be called harmonic sequence (beside being geometric and arithmetic)?
Sequence 1,1,1,1 or for example 5,5,5,5 is arithmetic and geometric, but can it also be harmonical or some other type of sequence?

Technically, yes. A harmonic sequence is the reciprocal of an arithmetic sequence. Therefore, if you allow for the difference between consecutive terms to be $0$ is arithmetic sequences, constant sequences are arithmetic. Hence, constant sequences are also harmonic.

Yes, as harmonic progression is the reciprocal of an arithmetic Progression, any sequence containing repeating numbers can be considered harmonic with common difference equal to zero.
Except For 0,0,0.. this is not harmonic as 1/0 is not defined.
